# Arbitrary long sequences of positive integers without prime powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that there are arbitrarily long sequences of positive integers without prime powers. I know how the proof goes for primes, but how is it different for prime powers?

Answer (score 3):

Take $n=2^{2k}$, so that $n$ is a square. Moreover it is easy to see that for all the perfect powers $1<x^t\le n$, the exponent $t$ cannot exceed $2k$.

How many are the powers (2nd, 3rd,... $2k$-th) smaller or equal to $n$ ?

The squares are $2^k$. The other powers, with exponents from $3$ to $2k$ are clearly much less, but since we are interested in a bound, let's just assume there are at most $2^k$ of each of them.

All in all, up to $n=2^{2k}$ there are thus less than $2k \cdot 2^k$ perfect powers. So, on the average there is less than a perfect power every $2^{2k}/(2k 
\cdot 2^k) = 2^k/(2k)$ numbers and thus there must be at least a gap larger than that.

Since we can make grow $2^k/(2k)$ as large as we want, gaps are unbounded.

Comment: you can do a bit better by arguing that between two consecutive squares, there can be at most one cube, one $5$th power, one $7$th power, etc up to one $(2k-1)$th power.

Comment: Nice combinatorial proof